# From JSON to object without table name

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm trying to Parse very simply JSON to object (with GSON)

My JSON:

```
[{"username":"admin","password":"admin","name":"admin","email":"admin@admin.com"},{"username":"mark20","password":"mark123","name":"mark","email":"mark@steew.com"}]
```

is there 2 users, so I create 2 class, Users with list of users and User :

```
public class Users {

    ArrayList<User> users;

    Users(ArrayList<User> users){
        this.users = users;
    }

}
```

.

```
public class User {

    String userame;
    String password;
    String name;
    String email;

}
```

and here is my parsing code:

```
public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            String body = response.body().string();
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            Users users = gson.fromJson(body, Users.class);
        }
```

of course in variable `body` I have got correct JSON, but in last lane I got:

```
JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY
```

What can be wrong here ? How to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json is an array of `User` not a wrapper `Users` of array `User`.

Read your json like this:

```
User[] users = gson.fromJson(body, User[].class);
```

If you want an `ArrayList<>`:

```
List<User> userList = Arrays.asList(users);
```

Another way is to use `TypeToken`:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<User>>(){}.getType();
List<User> userList = gson.fromJson(body, listType);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading from what I read elsewhere correctly try:

```
public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            String body = response.body().string();
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            User[] users = gson.fromJson(body, User[].class);
        }
```